# jquery mobile - changePage does not work with pageinit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is the sample code (test.html),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="content" id="content">Page 1</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="content" id="content" >Page 2</div>
</div>

<script>
$('#page2').live('pageinit',function(evt) {
    $.mobile.changePage($('#page1'),{allowSamePageTransition:true})
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to accessing ./test.html#page2 using both Firefox and Chrome, it is expected to change to page1. But it is NOT ALWAYS changed to page1 successfully. Sometimes, it still remains unchanged in page2. Any one know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try as below

```
$('#page2').on('pageshow',function(evt) {
    $.mobile.changePage($('test.html#page1'),{allowSamePageTransition:true})
});
```

and another piece of advice with my experience is that nested JQM pages results in amble of navigation errors. As a thumb rule, I always have separate pages for my JQM HTML pages.